# Blob's slice method works incorrectly in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to `slice` a big file as follows:

```
function alertChunk(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
            alert(e.target.result);
        }
    };

    if (file.slice) {
        var blob = file.slice(1000, 1000);
    } else if (file.mozSlice) {
        var blob = file.mozSlice(1000, 1000);
    } else if (file.webkitSlice) {
        var blob = file.webkitSlice(1000, 1000);
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
```

HTML as follows:

```
<input type="file" onchange="alertChunk(this.files[0])" />
```

But I do get an empty result in Chrome, though it works well in Firefox. Does anybody know why it can be empty? What is wrong?

NB: It seems to work well in Chrome when I do as follows:

```
var blob = file.webkitSlice(10, 1000); // changed the start index
```

But it won't work with a bigger index!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FileReader interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) is part of the [W3C File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) that is still just a working draft so you can expect it to be inconsistenly implemented across browsers.

ECMA-262 specifies slice as *String.prototype.slice(start, end)* where *start* and *end* reference characters in a string. I expect that if `start == end` then nothing will be sliced.

The W3C File API working draft specifies *[File.slice(start, length[, contentType])](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-slice)* where *start* and *length* are byte offsets. The optional *[contentType](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-contentTypeBlob)* parameter may allow setting the content to ASCII text or similar.

So it appears that Chrome's *File.slice* may well be implemented per the ECMA-262 String method rather than the W3C File API method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solves my problem. Indeed, it works as you explain. This also describes `webkitSlice`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob